# Combine two mongo aggregate query results into one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two mongo aggregate pipelines that output results. Now I want combine these two pipelines to have a singular output.

Please find below sample collection.

```
[
  {
    _id: "ddfdfdfdggfgfgsg",
    rate: "3323",
    quantity_packs: "343",
    shop_name: "Whole Foods",
    sku: "20"
    manufacturer_name: "Unilever"
  },
  {
    _id: "ddfdfdfsdsds",
    rate: "434",
    quantity_packs: "453",
    shop_name: "Carrefour",
    sku: "200"
    manufacturer_name: "Unilever"
  },
  {
    _id: "dfdfdgcvgfgfvvv",
    rate: "343",
    quantity_packs: "23",
    shop_name: "Target",
    manufacturer_name: "Beirsdorf"
    sku: "34"
  }
]
```

Please find below my queries.

**First Query**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            manufacturer_name: {
                $in: [ "unilever" ]
            }
        }
    }, 

    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "Shop Name": "$shop_name"
            },

            "total_sku": {
                "$addToSet": "$sku"
            },

            "annual_cost": {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        {
                            $eq: ["$manufacturer_name", "unilever"]
                        },
                        {
                            "$toDouble": "$rate"
                        }, 
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },

            "annual_qty": {
                $sum: {
                    "$toDouble": "$annual_qty"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            "sku count": {
                "$size": "$total_sku"
            },

            "Annual Cost WO GST": {
                $multiply: [ "$annual_cost", "$annual_qty" ]
            },
        }
    },
])
```

**Result of First Query**

```
[
  {
    _id: { 'Hospital Name': '7AM mart' },
    'sku count': 29,
    'Annual Cost WO GST': 79968887.67999999
  },
  {
    _id: { 'Shop Name': 'Apex' },
    'sku count': 20,
    'Annual Cost WO GST': 1779192666.96
  }
]
```

**Second Query**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $ne: ["$manufacturer_name", "unilever"]
            }
        }
    }, 

    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "Shop Name": "$shop_name"
            },
            
            "annual_cost_wo_gst_wo_manu": {
                $sum: {
                    "$toDouble": "$rate"
                }
            },

            "annual_qty": {
                $sum: {
                    "$toDouble": "$annual_qty"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            "Ann Cost For Other Manufacturers": {
                $multiply: ["$annual_cost_wo_gst_wo_manu", "$annual_qty"]
            },
        }
    }
])
```

**Result of Second Query**

```
[
  {
    _id: { 'Hospital Name': 'Apex' },
    'Ann Cost For Other Manufacturers': 25246715130525.273
  },
  {
    _id: { 'Hospital Name': '7AM Mart' },
    'Ann Cost For Other Manufacturers': 1347701834351.495
  }
]
```

As mentioned above, I somehow want to combine to results by **correctly mapping** the items.

**Intended Result**

```
[
      {
        _id: { 'Hospital Name': '7AM mart' },
        'sku count': 29,
        'Annual Cost WO GST': 79968887.67999999
        'Ann Cost For Other Manufacturers': 1347701834351.495
      },
      {
        _id: { 'Shop Name': 'Apex' },
        'sku count': 20,
        'Annual Cost WO GST': 1779192666.96
        'Ann Cost For Other Manufacturers': 25246715130525.273
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 queries do not quite produce your stated outputs. Nevertheless, you could first perform uncorrelated `$lookup` to perform your second query, storing the result of your secondary query in a field/object. Then you can continue your first query. Finally extract the result of secondary query from the previously stored field/object.

Here is a [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1WFxbw_WgX1) with some modifications to your original examples for your reference.

Comment: Hi ray…the sku count and annual cost is showing zero values.

Comment: It's because from your given dataset, the fields sku is not provided. You may want to update your provided sample dataset again.

Comment: Oops...added SKU key in the collection dataset. Sorry :)

Comment: The playground link is updated =] What I want to emphasize is the idea of putting your secondary query into $lookup sub-pipeline. The other field projections should be relatively easy to follow.

Comment: Hi ray…thank you for answering. The sku count is 1 instead of showing the number and both kinds of annual costs are showing same values.

Comment: The playground link is based on the 2 queries your provided with slight modification. One of the examples would be: from your raw example, both queries will return no document as the 'unilever' is the small letter instead of capital letter. I would suggest you review your given examples, provide 2 working playgound links that can show your expected logic for the 2 queries so people here can have more details to understand your needs. On the other hand, you may try to understand the concept of the $lookup sub-pipline and see if you can apply it on your side.

Comment: Hi Ray...I have gone through the playground link.  I have understood what you were trying to do with the query. However, when I make Unilever to capital letters, i am getting no document found. The sample collection dataset is correct. https://mongoplayground.net/p/HvUeYLJ5mb5